# how can I use toastrservice in my S3Uploader class?

Tags: angular

I am trying to upload a file directly to AWS S3 using angular. I have a component of file upload on s3 which is using s3 uploader and few other classes which I am exporting in the component. now I want to show the toastr at success. I was thinking that I will use toastrService at this function

```
 upload(event) {
        let file = event.srcElement.files[0];
        this.uploader.upload(file).then(x => {
          console.log(x);

        });
        console.log(this.config);
      }
```

which is inside a component, so I can easily use toastrService here but s3 is not giving me any response. it is giving me 204 status message

I have tried using var toastr:Toastrservice:   but  it is giving me undefined.
my code snippet.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { StorageService } from "../../../shared/services/storage-service/storage.service";
 import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
declare var CryptoJS: any;
declare var toastr: ToastrService;

@Component({
  selector: "app-slots-upload",
  templateUrl: "./slots-upload.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./slots-upload.component.css"]
})
export class SlotsUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  color = "primary";
  mode = "indeterminate";
  value = 50;
  bufferValue = 75;
  currentUser;
  uploader: S3Uploader;
  imagePath: string;
  config = new S3Config();
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private storageService: StorageService,
   // private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(this.storageService.getToken());
    console.log(this.currentUser);
    if (this.currentUser.role === "Admin") {
      this.config.accessKey = this.currentUser.accessKey;
      this.config.bucket = this.currentUser.bucketNameSlot;
      this.config.secretAccessKey = this.currentUser.secretKey;
      this.config.region = this.currentUser.regionVal;
      console.log(this.config);
    }
    this.uploader = new S3Uploader();

    // Input your S3 Config
    this.uploader.init(http, this.config);
  }

  upload(event) {
    let file = event.srcElement.files[0];
    this.uploader.upload(file).then(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
    console.log(this.config);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}

export class S3Config {
  bucket: string;
  accessKey: string;
  secretAccessKey: string;
  region: string;
  folder: string;
}

export class S3Uploader {
         private config: S3Config;
         private http: Http;
         private toastr: ToastrService;
         init(http: Http, config: S3Config) {
           this.http = http;
           this.config = config;
         }

         upload(file: any): Promise<any> {
           let date = this.generateTimestamp();
           let datetime = date + "T000000Z";

           let credential = `${this.config.accessKey}/${date}/${this.config.region}/s3/aws4_request`;

           let policy = JSON.stringify({
             expiration: new Date(Date.now() + 100000).toISOString(),
             conditions: [
               { bucket: this.config.bucket },
               ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
               { acl: "public-read" },
               ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
               { "x-amz-credential": credential },
               { "x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" },
               { "x-amz-date": datetime }
             ]
           });

           let policyBase64 = window.btoa(policy);
           let signatureKey = this.generateSignatureKey(this.config.secretAccessKey, date, this.config.region, "s3");
           let signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(policyBase64, signatureKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
           let formData = new FormData();

           formData.append("acl", "public-read");
           formData.append("Content-Type", file.type);
           formData.append("X-Amz-Date", datetime);
           formData.append("X-Amz-Algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
           formData.append("X-Amz-Credential", credential);
           formData.append("X-Amz-Signature", signature);
           formData.append("Policy", policyBase64);
           formData.append("key", file.name);
           formData.append("file", file);

           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             this.http
               .post(
                 `https://${this.config.bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/`,
                 formData
               )
               .subscribe(
                 x => {
                   console.log(x);
                   if ( x.status === 204) {
                    console.log('success');
                  //  console.log(this.toastr);
                    console.log(toastr);
                   }
               //    this.toastr.success("uploaded");
                   resolve(x.headers.get("Location"));
                 },
                 x => {
                   console.error(x);
                   reject();
                 }
               );
           });
         }

         generateSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
           let kDate = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
           let kRegion = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
           let kService = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
           let kSigning = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

           return kSigning;
         }

         generateTimestamp() {
           let date = new Date();
           let year = date.getFullYear();
           let month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
           let day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
           return year + month + day;
         }
       }
```

Comment: Did you put somewhere <toaster-container></toaster-container> in your html. May be this is the reason.

Comment: no. html is plain and simple. just this 
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xlsx" />

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your S3Uploader:

```
constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService
  )
```

and also use @Inject() decorator on your S3Uploader class. @Inject() decorator will tell angular to use dependency injection in your class and will provide instance of ToastrService.

Use following line of code to show toaster:

```
this.toastr.success("your message");
```

Comment: hey, In the SlotsUploadComponent,  I can use it in this way but as I said I have to use it in S3Uploader class and by doing this way, it is giving Property 'toaster' does not exist on type 'S3Uploader'

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know it worked for u or not.

Comment: I have tried this initially.  alone  it won't work,but  if I provide it like  this.uploader = new S3Uploader(this.toaster); then it will work. thanks :)

Comment: @SandipJaiswal hey please can you tell me the use of ToastrService?